# Is there an SVG path d convention for using z instead of coordinate with other segments?

Tags: svg

I've tried to explore a python library for SVG parsing named [svgelements](https://pypi.org/project/svgelements/). And there is an unusual concept I can't find in any SVG docs, also nor dolphin file browser nor firefox nor gimp can't render svg files using this. There is a `z` in pathd parsed as a coordinate and passed to `Path` to create the curve or line with `z_point` (the end of last move operation). So `z` used with `LQTCS` operations to replace a coordinate.
Is it something standard for SVG? And why many other apps can't process this?

I've explored this code for path d parsing
https://github.com/meerk40t/svgelements/blob/master/svgelements/svgelements.py#L408

There's a part with z as number processing

Comment: If I understand you right, it allows a path string like `M0,0 2,0 Q 1,1 z`, substituting the `z` with `0,0` so that the closing path is a Bezier, not a straight line?

Comment: @ccprog yes, this parser does exactly this. So it will process `M0,0 2,0 Q 1,1 z` as `M0,0 2,0 Q 1,1 0,0`. But none of librsvg or qt's qsvgrenderer won't process the `Q 1,1 z` part. As well as there's no information about this in svgrequirements. So should I consider this as mistake in this python library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The library is implementing something that is actually part of the SVG 2 specification: [Segment-completing close path operation](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/paths.html#Segment-CompletingClosePath). There is a (apparently failing) [test](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:third_party/blink/web_tests/external/wpt/svg/path/closepath/segment-completing.svg) in the Chromium test suite that exemplifies what is meant. It gives the test path element:

```
 <path d="M 10 10 z m 20 70 h 10 v 10 h -10 l z M 70 30 q 20 0 20 20 t -20 20 t -20 -20 T z" />
```

To make it clear: since SVG 1.0 the `z` command closes any path in a straight line. **This** variant makes it possible to define the closing segment as a curved line.

Unfortunately, that part of the specification looks a bit like a dead end. [This issue](https://github.com/w3c/svgwg/issues/893) of the W3C SVG working group from August says:

> The spec for the Segment-completing close path operation command was added 4 years ago and hasn't been implemented by any browser yet.
> (https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/paths.html#PathDataClosePathCommand). Currently it only exists in the spec, and as a failing wpt test.

> consider removing it from the spec?

So far, there has been no further discussion as it seems.

Answer (score 0):

ccprog's answer is spot on. I will say the actual library itself is located at:
https://github.com/meerk40t/svgelements

(full disclosure, I wrote it)

---

Yeah, it's a path closing syntax that's effectively dead-ended. And I would actually recommend staying clear since it will harm portability. In fact, if you feed that data into a path, and ask for the `.d()` of the path you will not get the same syntax back because the cross compatibility is non-existent. (This won't break things since the original SVG 1.0 syntax is still valid and it would be strange to use this synax if you don't know that it exists).

Also, `"In order to represent the basic shapes as equivalent paths, there must be a way to close curved shapes without introducing an additional straight-line segment (even if that segment would have zero length)."` is pretty much dead too since nobody actually implemented the decompositions there either.

A circle, for example, is decomposed as 4 clockwise 90° circular arc segments. That end with a close. This decomposed circle does not end with a 0-length line and a close. It's to end with an arc that closes. So if you added code to add markers at those locations you should have each point around the circle get a  marker. But, this too isn't implemented literally anywhere, markers don't work on shapes, and for a circle you'd have coincident `start-marker` and `end-marker` but no `mid-marker` at angle 0. I'm guessing this sort of ambiguity is part of the reason nobody implemented and the WC3 is pretty clear that if nobody implements it, it gets cut from the spec.

While the Z syntax there made no visible difference it did make a difference with regard to the datastructure and that's more my concern when I wrote that stuff up (when you're dealing with the path as a sequence like the library does 0 distance lines actually exist), and then after nobody implemented it, I couldn't cut it for backwards compatibility reasons. So you can totally use it, but it'll just result in a bit of a different path which you could have composed with the tools otherwise.